# Is this process strictly positive?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, pr.probability

Let $W_t$ is standard Brownian motion under probability measure $P$.
Consider 1-D stochastic differential equation
$$ dY_t = dt + \sigma(Y_t) dW_t, \ Y_0 = y\ge 0.$$
We assume $\sigma(0) = 0$, and $\sigma(x)$ is locally Holder-1/2, i.e.
for any bounded subinterval $I\subset [0,\infty)$,
we assume there exists constant $K_I$ s.t.
$$|\sigma(x_1)- \sigma(x_2)| \le K_I |x_1 - x_2|^{1/2}, \ \forall x_1, x_2 \in I.$$
Note that, the above SDE has strong non-negative solution by comparison with
$d X_t = \sigma(X_t) dW_t$.

[Q1] Define $\tau = \inf[t>0: Y_t = 0]$. Is $\tau>0$ almost surely?

[Q2] Can one show that $Y_t > 0$ almost surely for arbitrary given $t>0$?

In fact, it's enough to show the above results with $y= 0$.

My guess is that, [Q2] is too strong to be true, but [Q1] is correct.
It will be helpful to get a proof of [Q1] at least.

Comment: why don't you use the scale function ? 

Comment: @Mike, could you be more specific? I have difficulty use scale function, since $\sigma^{-2}$ may not be locally integrable at $0$.
I am assuming initial $y = 0$.

Comment: Suppose you divide it into 2 cases, one where $\sigma = 0$ in an interval near $0$, and the other where $\exists x_i \rightarrow 0 $ with $\sigma(x_i) = 0$.  If $\ell_i = sup \lbrace x < x_i : \sigma(x) = 0$ then it seems to me that you can show that a process started from $x_i$ never hits $\ell_i$.  Then, if the process is positive with probability 1 at time t it would postive with probability 1 for all t.

Comment: should have read $\sigma(x_i) > 0$, 

Comment: @kenneth: You can answer Q1 by comparing with a Bessel squared process, and the answer depends on the value of $K_I$. On the other hand, Q2 doesn't look very strong to me. I expect that the answer is an unconditional yes.

Comment: To continue George's comment, the exact probabilities of hitting zero for the BESQ-process are given e.g. in Delbaen and Shirakawa, A Note of Option Pricing for Constant Elasticity of Variance Model, http://www.math.ethz.ch/~delbaen/ftp/preprints/CEV.pdf

Comment: @George, I apologize for [Q2], which seems trivial. I meant to ask, instead
[Q2'] If $\tau = \infty$ almost surely?




Comment: @Steve, It's helpful to have the paper. I guess you are saying Cor 3.6 of the paper. However, the probability is about
the probability of $Y_u$ hits zero during $0\le u \le t$. In particular, if $y = 0$, then this probability is 1 always. In fact, we need the same hitting probability during $0< u \le t$.

Answer (score 0):

First by the [Yamada–Watanabe](https://fam.tuwien.ac.at/%7Eschmock/notes/Yamada-Watanabe.pdf) theorem, we have existence and uniqueness at least locally.

[image]

Second, we indeed show that the solution cannot be negative. Here we can follow a similar argument as in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4135941/proving-that-the-solution-to-the-cox-ingersoll-ross-sde-is-positive). Since we restricted to $[0,\infty)$ we can consider the sde

$$dZ_{t}=dt+\sigma(Z_{t}\vee 0)dW_{t}, Z_{0}=z_{0}\geq 0$$

for fixed $\epsilon>0$, the hitting time $\tau_{-\epsilon}:=\inf\{t>0: Z_{t}=-\epsilon\}$. We want to show that $P[\tau_{-\epsilon}=\infty]=1$. Suppose otherwise, then there is a short enough interval $I=(\tau_{-\epsilon}(\omega)-u,\tau_{-\epsilon}(\omega))$ so that for $t\in I$ we have $Z_{t}<0$ and

$$dZ_{t}=dt+\sigma(0)dW_{t}=dt\Rightarrow Z_{t}=t+z_{0}>0,$$

which is a contradiction.

Finally, indeed as mentioned in the comments the claim $P[\tau_{0}=\infty]=1$ or $<1$ depends on the volatility versus drift relationship. For example, in [Bessel processes](https://almostsuremath.com/2010/07/28/bessel-processes/) $dX_{t}=ndt+2\sqrt{X_{t}}dW_{t}$ we have
[image]

In terms of positive-direction results,

- In ["An Euler-type method for the strong approximation of the Cox-Ingersoll-Ross process"](https://www.uni-muenster.de/Stochastik/dereich/Publikationen/Preprints/cir.pdf) for the CIR process $dXt = \kappa(\lambda − X_t) dt + \sigma \sqrt{X_t} dW_t , X_0 = x_0$, a main idea is using the Feller-explosion test in Karatzas-Shreeve theorem 5.29

[image]

- see here ["Fractional Cox–Ingersoll–Ross process with non-zero «mean»"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.01677.pdf) for a nice approach with last sup time.
- For a result in positive direction [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2810419/show-that-this-stochastic-process-is-a-s-strictly-positive)

> $$dX_t = f(X_t)dt + \sigma(X_t)dW_t,\quad X_0 = 1,$$
> where $W_t$ is a Brownian motion under the measure $\mathbb{P}$, in its natural filtration. Suppose that $f(x)-\sigma^2(x)/2x=0$ and $\sigma^2(x)\le x^2$. Show that $X_t>0$ almost surely.

Comment: Hi, how do you get that $dZ_t = dt + \sigma(0) \, dW_t$?

Comment: this is similar to the answer in the MSE post. Here too the OP defines $\sigma:[0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ and so sigma doesn't take negative values.