# Uniqueness of the solution to stochastic differential equation

Tags: stochastic-differential-equations

Let $W$ be a Brownian motion and consider the SDE

$$dX_t = b(t,X_t) \, dt + a(t,X_t)\,dW_t,\quad \forall t\ge 0. \tag{$\ast$} $$

Assume that $x\mapsto b(t,x), a(t,x)$ are locally Lipschitz in $x$ uniformly in $t$, i.e. for any $T>0$ and $R>0$, there exists $L>0$ s.t.

$$|b(t,x)-b(t,y)|+ |a(t,x)-a(t,y)| \le L|x-y|,\quad \forall 0\le t\le T,~~ |x|, |y|\le R.$$

Then $(\ast)$ admits at most one solution $(X^{s,z})_{t\ge s}$ for any initial condition $X^{s,z}_s=z$. If $X^{0,0}_t\equiv 0$ is a solution to $(\ast)$, do we have

$$\mathbb P[X^{0,z}_t\neq 0, \forall t\ge 0]=1,\quad \forall z\neq 0 \text{?}$$

Any answer, comments and references are highly appreciated.

Comment: do you have a specific SDE in mind? this would make it easier to answer because now we might not even have existence for all $t\geq 0$ and $z\neq 0$ and so the event is not well-posed.

Comment: @ThomasKojar More precisely, consider the SDE of the form $dX_t = C(t,X_t)X_t dW_t$, where $C$ is some "suitable" function. Can we say in the case that if $X_0\neq 0$ then $X_t\neq 0$ for all $t\ge 0$?

Comment: I would include in the post so that it gets answered on this specific context. Also, do you have any idea for "suitable" i.e what kind of regularity are you looking for $C$ eg. locally Lipschitz continuous also? because ,say, if $C=X^a/X $ for $a>0$ , then it again might have problems with finite explosion time https://almostsuremath.com/2010/02/25/sdes-with-locally-lipschitz-coefficients/ and thus not defined for all t? and if you have an even more specific C that would make it easier.

Comment: But in any case, for this particular example, I would look into Feller's explosion time in Karatzas-Shreve. If you can show that the explosion time is infinite, then it will indeed never cross the real line for all t.

Comment: see here for similar situation https://mathoverflow.net/questions/103755/is-this-process-strictly-positive/439384#439384

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First for the case of time-independent coefficients (autonomous). A good setting for this question is the Feller-explosion test (see here [Is this process strictly positive?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/103755/is-this-process-strictly-positive/439384#439384) for related question). The Feller-explosion test in Karatzas-Shreeve theorem 5.29

[image]

So for the case mentioned in the comments, we assume weak solution existence in interval $(0,r)$ and we want to check $X_{t}>0$ for all $t\geq 0$. The Feller-explosion test, says never exiting $(0,b)$ (i.e. $P(S_{(0,b)}=\infty)=1$)  is equivalent to a condition on the scale functions. Here

$$v(x):=\int_{x_{0}}^{x}p'(x)\int_{x_{0}}^{y}\frac{2}{p'(z)\sigma^{2}(z)}dz,$$

where $p(x):=\int_{x_{0}}^{x}exp(-2\int_{x_{0}}^{\xi}\frac{b(y)}{\sigma^{2}(y)}dy)d\xi$, for $b$ the drift and $\sigma$ the volatility coefficient.

In the case of time-dependent coefficients (non-autonomous) as in the question $\sigma(t,X_{t})$, there is still an analogue of Feller-explosion i.e. non-escape and thus strictly positive in the work ["On the Distribution of Explosion Time of Stochastic Differential Equations."](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1305.2870.pdf).

[image]

where they look at a generalization

[image]

It seems the fully non-autonomous case is still open for very general coefficients.

Comment: Thx a lot for the detailed answer